# Как в javaScript связать две функции

Tags: jquery, функции, javascript

Добрый вечер!
Есть функция

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setBigImage(foto) {
$("#adpdp14").attr('href', $(foto).parent('.it').children('a').attr('href'));
document.getElementById("dp14").src = foto.src;
}
</script>
```

и инициализация второй

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $(a.fullsizable).fullsizable({
        clickBehaviour: 'next'
      });
    });
</script>
```

и сама див структура (устанавливает в первый большой div миниатюры, по которым кликаешь в нижнем div'е)

```
<div class="photo">
            <div  class="img">
                <a href="1.jpg" id="adpdp14" class="fullsizable" onclick='fullsizable(this);'><img src="1.jpg" id="dp14" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs" >
                <div class="it"><a style="display:none;" href="1.jpg" rel="example_group" ></a>
                    <img src="1.jpg" onclick='setBigImage(this);' alt="" /></div>
                <div class="it"><a style="display:none;" href="2.jpg" rel="example_group" class="fullsizable"></a>
                    <img src="2.jpg" onclick='setBigImage(this);' alt="" /></div>
                <div class="it"><a style="display:none;" href="3.jpg" rel="example_group" class="fullsizable"></a>
                    <img src="3.jpg" onclick='setBigImage(this);' alt="" /></div>
                <div class="it"><a style="display:none;" href="4.jpg" rel="example_group" class="fullsizable"></a>
                    <img src="4.jpg" onclick='setBigImage(this);' alt="" /></div>
            </div>
```

Как срастить обе функции, как сделать инициализацию второй не по тегу <а> с классом .fullsizable, а по значению, на которое меняет id="adpdp14" из первой функции и при этом чтобы фотки листались, а не просто открывался в верхнем div'e текущий адрес id="adpdp14"?

Comment: Для начала не делайте так:

`<a href="1.jpg" id="adpdp14" class="fullsizable" onclick='fullsizable(this);'>`

Comment: @eicto, я видел, вы много где писали, что нельзя использовать подобные конструкции onclick='setBigImage(this);'. А почему?

Comment: Ну я подробно и писал уже: 

* вызываемые функции в глобал;
* jQuery (а тут именно он) использует собственный поток событий, который так будет нарушен;
* конкретно тут ещё и [DRY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @eicto, все яснопонятно.

Comment: @mountpoint, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_JavaScript

@besimpl, не совсем понял вашу проблему. Вам нужно при клике на миниатюру показывать эту картинку в верхнем диве? И меня пугает использование document.getElementById совместно с jQuery, зачем?

Comment: @http://hashcode.ru/users/12995/andreyqin
Да, при клике показывать в верхнем диве, но это работает. А вообще смысл в том чтобы при клике как раз уже по верхнему диву заработала функция fullsizable, она открывает ее на весь экран, ну  соответственно листались фото на весь экран. А сейчас инициализация этой функции по (a.fullsizable), то есть первая функция меняет картинку, а fullsizableначинает работать с первой картики независимо от того что делает первая функция.

Comment: @eicto,
<a href="1.jpg" id="adpdp14" class="fullsizable" onclick='fullsizable(this);'>
)) - это случайность, я пробовал разные варианты, просто забыл код поменять, в одном месте поменял, а здесь он остался)
Так как все же мне поступить, чтобы работало?